# Assigning values to 2d arrays created by malloc

Tags: c

I am missing something basic about setting up 2d arrays using malloc and using pointer more specifically.  Right now I am just trying to fill up every array spot with an "a".  When I get to the placing "a" into array loop(2nd), I get this compiler error "assignment makes integer from pointer without cast".  Super confused, scoured the internet but I am at lost for resoures, and can't find the right ones.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(int argc, char **argv){
    char **myArray;
    int i=0, k=0;
    myArray = malloc(15);

    for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
        myArray[i] = malloc(10);
    }

    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
         for(k=0; k<10; k++){
              myArray[i][k] = "a";
         }
    }

    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
          for(k=0; k<10; k++){
                 printf("%c\n", myArray[i][k]);
          }
    }   

}
```

Comment: you need to use `strcpy` to copy strings

Comment: malloc(15) is not enough room to store 10 pointers

Comment: How much space is needed per pointer?

Comment: `sizeof(char*)` is needed per pointer (usually 4,varies per platform)

Answer (score 0):

`myArray[i][k] = "a";` is copying a pointer to a local string, not a char.

use 
`myArray[i][k] = 'a';`

when you want to print using `printf("%c\n", myArray[i][k]);`

Comment: It's not copying a string, it's copying (or attemptiong to copy) a pointer to a string literal

Answer (score 0):

```
myArray[i][k] = "a";
```

should be written as

```
myArray[i][k] = 'a';
```

"a" is a string literal

'a' is a character constant

The

```
myArray[i] = malloc(10)
```

allocates memory for 10 chars.

The warning for "assignment makes integer from pointer without cast"  suggests that it expects an integer, where as you are giving it a pointer value when using "a". Using 'a'(with single quotes) will translate to an integer ASCII value and will be able to store in a char datatype.

Answer (score 0):

Your allocation scheme is pretty bizzare:

```
char **myArray;
myArray = malloc(15); //You allocate 15 bytes in here
```

Try doing something like this:

```
myArray = malloc(15 * sizeof(char*));  /* allocate space for 15 char *-s */
/* Depending on your system this could be 60 or 120 bytes */
```

Now the compiler error is a completely different thing:

```
 myArray[i][k] = "a";
```

What it says is that a char value (integral type) is expected in the left hand side but you give it a string literal (char*); You could fix it by:

```
myArray[i][k] = 'a';
```

If what you want to do is to make that character an 'a'.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define SZ 10

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char** myArray;
    int i, j;

    myArray = malloc( SZ * sizeof(char*) );

    for(i=0;i<SZ;++i)
        myArray[i] = malloc(SZ);

    for(i=0;i<SZ;++i)
        for(j=0;j<SZ;++j)
            myArray[i][j] = 'a';

    for(i=0;i<SZ;++i)
        for(j=0;j<SZ;++j)
            printf("%c\n", myArray[i][j]);

    for(i=0;i<SZ;++i)
        free(myArray[i]);
    free(myArray);
}
```

Comment: You should at least provide *some* explanation behind your answer, rather than just respond with code.

Answer (score 0):

The program contains many errors.  For example what does mean the statement below?

```
myArray = malloc(15);
```

What is the meaning of the magic number 15?

The valid code could look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    const int N = 10;
    char **myArray;
    int i;

    myArray = ( char ** )malloc( N * sizeof( char * ) );

    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ ) myArray[i] = ( char * )malloc( N * sizeof( char ) );

    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ ) strcpy( myArray[i], "a" );

    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ ) printf("%s\n", myArray[i] );

    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ ) free( myArray[i] );

    free( myArray );
}
```

Or

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    const int N = 10;
    char **myArray;
    int i, k;

    myArray = ( char ** )malloc( N * sizeof( char * ) );

    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ ) myArray[i] = ( char * )malloc( N * sizeof( char ) );

    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( k = 0; k < N; k++ ) myArray[i][k] = 'a';
    }  

    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( k = 0; k < N; k++ ) printf( "%c", myArray[i][k] );
        puts( "" );
    }  

    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ ) free( myArray[i] );

    free( myArray );
}
```

Comment: the second malloc has a strange size. also, probably not want he wanted, with 1-dimesional array of strings

Comment: Your first example is incorrect - OP wants a 2D array of characters, not a 1D array of strings

Comment: @Drew McGowen You are totally wrong. The both my examples are correct. It is the example of OP that is incorrect.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow `Right now I am just trying to fill up every array spot with an "a".` sounds like OP wants a 2D array of characters, in which case your first example simply fills the first column (assuming row-major ordering) with `'a'`, the second column with `'\0'`, and leaving the rest of the columns undefined.

Comment: @Drew McGowen I am sorry but you have some problems with the intellect. I showed two possibilities either with using a string literal as an initializer of a character array or using a character literal as an initializer of each element of an array. He can choise what you like most. So there is only one problem that is the problem with your intellect.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow see http://ideone.com/elz826 and http://ideone.com/ShqMqu - the results are different

Comment: @Drew McGowen Of course the results are different. Did you think that the results will be the same?!

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I'm just saying that your first example is not doing what OP wants, which is to fill *every* spot with the character `'a'`. I'm guessing OP is probably assuming strings are like that in higher-level languages such as Python where single quotes vs double quotes don't matter (whereas they do in C).

Comment: @Drew McGowen Do I need to repeat all what I already wrote you?